# Double "will" or not

Tags: grammar, future-tense, future-perfect

Please consider the following sentences:

> 1. It is an act which will make the audience think that I (have/will have) used too much time.
> 2. The man never wants to buy her the ring, which will leave the impression that he (has/will have) bought her with it.

My question is: do we need to use "will" there just because they haven't happened? Or should we not use "will" because they are viewed from the particular future points in time?

Comment: Your second sentence doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: @marcellothearcane the ring will leave such an impression. It's a non-essential adjective clause.

Comment: Will just sounds wrong in both places. If you're looking for a conditional use *would* instead.

Comment: The problem with sentences that you have made up yourself- and especially with complex sentences like these- is that it's not clear what you are trying to say. If we don't know what you are trying to say, we can't comment on the correct way to say it.  Maybe you could choose a passage from a book as a basis for your sentence and then quote the passage from the book together with your made-up sentence.

Answer (score 1):

They mean different things.

If you use "will have" in those clauses, it means that the action of you using too much time and the action of buying her with it completes between now and then, meaning those actions have not yet happened or are not yet complete at the point in time the speaker is saying it but will happen or complete by the time that future time arrives, like at the future time when the audience thinks.

If you use "have"/"has" in those clauses, it means the action is presently in the past.  You're forecasting future events flowing from an action that is already complete in the present.

Comment: So, if I want to say that the audience will think so if I do the act, or the impression will come into existence if I buy her the ring, I should use "will have", right?